# Is $10^{100}$ (Googol) bigger than $100!$?

Tags: factorial

> Is $10^{100}$ (Googol) bigger than $100!$?
>
> If $10^{100}$ is called as Googol, does $100!$ have any special name to be called, apart from being called as "100 factorial"?

---

I ask this question because I get to know about the number $10^{100}$ on how big it is more often than $100!$. If $100!$ is bigger than $10^{100}$, then why don't we give more focus to $100!$ than the other number? Because for me, $100!$ looks simple.

Comment: Have you given this much thought of your own? For instance, have you even tried writing-out what $10^{100}$ and $100!$ equal? ... not the *final values*, mind you ... just the factors. Each of them has one hundred factors: the first has a lot of $10$s; the second has a few factors less than $10$, one factor equal to $10$, and *many* factors greater than $10$. What might this suggest to you?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with this question. Someone has downvoted.

Comment: I ask this question because I get to know about the number 10^100 on how big it is more often than 100!. If 100! is bigger than 10^100 means why don't we give much focus to 100! than the other number because for me 100! looks simple.

Comment: @Ramesh ignore the downvoters. It's unkind to downvote without a comment in my opinion. What they should have done IMO is leave a comment that you should show some effort on your own part. Anyway, I hope the answers below help you understand how to think about problems like this.

Answer (score 8):

With simple ineqalities we have:

$100!\geq 90^{10}\cdot 80^{10}\cdots 20^{10}\cdot 10^{10}$

$100!\geq (9\cdot 8 \cdots 2 \cdot 1)^{10}\cdot 10^{90}$

$100!\geq (9!)^{10}\cdot 10^{90}>10^{100}$

Comment: Nice & simple. And shows $100!$ is "a lot" larger, as in the last line, the ratio  of 
 $9!^{10}\cdot 10^{90} $ to $ 10^{100} $ is  $ (9!/10)^{10}=(3.6288)^{10}\cdot 10^{40}.$

Answer (score 1):

Before there was an error on the algebra, as pointed out in the comments. I try to fix the error following the same approach:

$100!=(1\times..\times 10)\times(11\times..\times 20)\times...\times(91\times..\times 100)=A_1...A_{10}$

so we estimate $A_i \ge 10^{10}$ for $i=2,..9$.

Instead we write $A_1A_{10}=(1\times 100)\times(2\times 99)\times(3 \times 97)\times...\times(10 \times 91)\ge (10^2)^{10}$.

Combining: $100!\ge (10^{10})^8 \times (10^2)^{10}=(10^{10})^{10}=10^{100}$.

Comment: I think 100^10 is 10^20 and not 10^100.

Answer (score 1):

Using $$n!>\bigg(\frac{n}{3}\bigg)^{n}, n>8$$

$$100!>\bigg(\frac{100}{3}\bigg)^{100}>10^{100}$$

Comment: You have a typo in the second formula

Comment: I think the solution works fine, but the condition $n>8$ is really necessary for the inequality ?